# What is required for RSVP and meeting invites to work in Outlook when using IMAP?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap, meeting-request, caldav

What is required for meeting invites and RSVP'ing to others' invites to work reliably in Outlook?
I mean unless you use Exchange/Office365, and with a calendar that would be sync'ed to my iPhone.

Some background information: I'm thinking about making the switch from Thunderbird to Outlook for my work email for better HTML email and calendar support. But I'd like to use a privacy-friendly provider like StartMail or ProtonMail, and they all only offer IMAP. And I'm not sure what I'd need for meeting requests to work. It seems like CalDav is usually used for this, but Outlook doesn't support it?

Comment: IMAP works. Make sure Outlook is set to have an OST file (cached mode) and have your email, calendar and contacts. This will sync with your iPhone. I use iTunes to sync the important things to my iPhone. Calendar acceptances work just fine.

Comment: I would need live online sync. I never connect my phone to my computer and I’m really not a fan of iTunes (which I feel never does what I want it to do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since nobody seemed to be able to come up with an answer, I thought I'd provide a quick update myself on what I've found out.

You can set up an Exchange account (such as a free account from outlook.com - as recommended by @Yuki Sun) as the first account in a fresh Outlook profile. This will link Outlook's calendar to that account.
You can then subsequently add as many IMAP accounts as you like, and they will all use the Exchange calendar and sending/accepting meeting invites. You can easily set up your iPhone to sync its calendar with the Exchange account. And you can just ignore the Exchange account in Outlook. The only downside is that all meeting invitations are sent from the Exchange account by default, so you need to manually change the sender address in Outlook. But I guess that's something one can live with.

I was unable to make any other solution work. They would all be some sort of hack. E.g. there is an "CalDavSynchronizer" add-in for Outlook, but it always resulted in duplicate meeting invitations being sent and was just a pain to use. That might have been due to the CalDav provider I was using, but it was extremely frustrating nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-basics-what-you-can-and-cannot-sync-5537d587-4930-4ac2-b044-3568509b1294), IMAP protocol is unable to sync calendar, contacts, etc. It can only sync email.

To view the up-to-date calendar of an IMAP account in Outlook, you may check if your email provider has the option to share the calendar in Internet Calendar (iCal) format, then you can subscribe it in Outlook. Below is a document about how to see Google calendar in Outlook for your reference:
[See your Google Calendar in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/see-your-google-calendar-in-outlook-c1dab514-0ad4-4811-824a-7d02c5e77126)

Comment: Thanks. I don’t just want to see my Google calendar. In fact I don’t care which calendar I use, I just want it to work like an Exchange calendar. Being able to read and write, send and receive meeting invites etc. It seems like that solution is read-only? Why is it so difficult to have a working setup? My Google address also differs from my email address (but I guess I could always make another Google account...).

Comment: Yes, it's a read-only solution."Changes you make in Outlook aren’t sent to your Google Calendar. To update your Google calendar, open Google Calendar from a browser." 
If this cannot meet your requirement, then I am afraid there's no other built-in features available in Outlook to sync a calendar from an IMAP account, this is by design as stated earlier. 
By the way, if Exchange/Microsoft account is not an option, personally I'd recommend using an outlook.com account which is free and can be configured as an Exchange account in Outlook client or mobile devices.